# How can i set up a sidebar that has dynamic content without editing all of my pages?

Tags: html, css, dynamic, web

How can i set up a sidebar that has dynamic content without editing all of my pages? I have tried iframes, but i cannot control the css specificaly

Comment: Just a couple of follow up questions: 1) Do you have `php` enabled on your site? 2) Do you have full access to the server you're using?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use PHP and have access to a server. If you're still building your site offline, you'll need to set up a local server with something like [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html).

To include the sidebar on a page, insert this command into your markup wherever you want the sidebar to be:

```
<body>
    ...
    <?php include "mySidebar.php" ?>
    ...
</body>
```

Then create a new file called "mySidebar.php" and write the markup for your sidebar. When you load your page, all the markup you have written in "mySidebar.php" will replace the php include line. Make sure "mySidebar.php" is in the same folder as the pages using it, or if you want to save it elsewhere you must specify the path to it in your php include.

**Also to use PHP, convert all your .html files to .php.